# Android Volley read and store HTTP Header

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a node backend, which returns the `id, email and JWT token` of an user after login. Id and email are set in the *JSON response body and the token* is set as a HTTP header.

What I want to do is just read that token from the header and store it for future requests until the user logs out, since I am deleting the token afterwards.

I found several posts about how to set the header by overriding `getHeaders()` and how to read the header by overriding `parseNetworkResponse()`. My problem with `parseNetworkResponse()` is, that I would have to write the information on the JSON body, which I want to avoid. My other problem with `getHeaders()` is that I can't "hardcode" my header into the HashMap, because I have to use the `JWT token` generated from the server.

This is my first Android project and overall I believe it's a simple use case but I am confused a bit at this point, so any help would be much appreciated.

**Relevant Code:**

```
// AuthenticationRequest.java
public class AuthenticationRequest extends JsonObjectRequest{

    public AuthenticationRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject payload,
                                 Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, payload, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            // I could fetch here with response.headers

            return Response.success(jsonResponse, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}

// BasicActivity.java
private void sendRequestToServer(String url, int method, JSONObject payload, final Class toGo) {
        final AuthenticationRequest request =
                new AuthenticationRequest(method, url, payload, response -> {
                    try {
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, toGo).putExtra("jsonData", response.toString()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

Comment: You're using a class that's already accessing the headers:  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpHeaderParser.java/

Comment: @Submersed At first thanks for helping :) I am aware of that. What I try to achieve is to store the concrete header `x-auth` (generated by me server-side) permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after playing around a bit I solved my issue. I created a `TokenHandler` class which is really basic and just cares about setting/getting and later deleting a token.

**TokenHandler.java**

```
public final class TokenHandler {
    private TokenHandler() {}

    private static String token = "";

    public static void setToken(String newToken) {
        if (newToken != null)
            token = newToken;
    }

    public static String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

And you set it up on your sub-classed Request like this:

**AuthRequest.java**

```
public class AuthRequest extends JsonObjectRequest{

    // constructor

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            // set token after receiving from login response
            TokenHandler.setToken(response.headers.get("x-auth"));

            return Response.success(jsonResponse, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("x-auth", TokenHandler.getToken());
        return headers;
    }
}
```