# Using Volley's library to Parse Headers from HTTP Response (Android)

Tags: android, http, header, android-volley

I'm hoping to use Volley's library to include headers from a response in Android. I know there are other tools like OkHttp, Retrofit, Moshi, Picasso that have more documentation for this (one of the cons of Volley I think -- little documentation). Yet I've already vested a lot of time into it.

I just want to translate a curl --include -X POST -d ... request into android.

So far, I have the POST working, but not the --include (helpful tutorial at https://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put):

```
public class HTTPService {

public static void makeRequest(Context context) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    Response.Listener responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response!=null){
                Log.d("Response", response);
                Log.d("Response", Integer.toString(response.length()));
            }
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // error
            String response = "Error";
            Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
        }
    };

    String url = "http://httpbin.org/post";


    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, responseListener, errorListener) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "John");
            params.put("domain", "https://www.facebook.com");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return super.getHeaders();
        }
        };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
}
```

I have shown the getHeaders function to illustrate that this is NOT what I want. That is to put headers ON your data. I want to INCLUDE HTTP headers in my response object.

Two links I have found are supposed to describe how to do this:

1) https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

2) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/android-4.3_r0.9/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java

But I get very confused at this point and... could anyone provide a working solution? Or tell me how they address the curl -i/--include command?

Answer (score 0):

Searching on google, I only see ways to access the header information (like --include) is from within the Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) function from Volley. The following is from user thedude's answer at [Android Volley read and store HTTP Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182171/android-volley-read-and-store-http-header).

```
@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        // set token after receiving from login response
        TokenHandler.setToken(response.headers.get("x-auth"));

        return Response.success(jsonResponse, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

Because this is a static context, the only way I've found to store the information is as a public variable of another class. The answer fromm thedude uses a TokenHandler.java class:

```
public final class TokenHandler {
private TokenHandler() {}

private static String token = "";

public static void setToken(String newToken) {
    if (newToken != null)
        token = newToken;
}

public static String getToken() {
    return token;
}
}
```